# How to create a self generating agreement page on checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I need to create an agreement document on the fly with the customer information like name, address etc.

Customer has to click the checkbox to confirm before proceed to payment process.

It is most likely a terms and conditions page with customer information.

Is it possible?

You may see an example of it below to find which parts of the file will be  filled on the fly:

All the red parts should be filled with customer and cart information.
[Agreement form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzN3I.png)

```
<div style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; line-height: 18px;">
<p>INFORMATION FORM</p>
<p>1. SELLER INFORMATION</p>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Company</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td>Placeholder &nbsp;(Referred to as "Seller")</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Address</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td>Placeholder</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Phone</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td>Placeholder</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">E-mail</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td>Placeholder</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>2. CLIENT INFORMATION</p>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Name / Sirname</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td style="color: red;">**********</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Shipping Address</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td style="color: red;">**********</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">Phone</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td style="color: red;">**********</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 130px;">E-mail</td>
            <td style="width: 10px;">:</td>
            <td style="color: red;">**********</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<p>4. AGREEMENT SUBJECT AND THE PRODUCT SPECS</p>
<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080;"><b>Product</b></td>
            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080;"><b>Quantity</b></td>
            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080;"><b>Price</b></td>
            <td style="width: 150px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080;"><b>Total</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">Arduino Uno R3 SMD Klon CH340 Chip</td>
<td style="width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">*</td>
<td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
<td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">LattePanda Windows 10 2G/32GB</td>
            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">*</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ Plus</td>
            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">*</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">BBC Micro:Bit Dev Card</td>
            <td style="width: 50px; text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; color: red;">*</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
            <td style="text-align: center; height: 25px; border: 1px solid #808080; width: 150px; color: red;">$***</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table style="border: 1px solid #808080; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 24px; font-size: 12px;" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px;">Shipping</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px; text-align: right; width: 150px; color: red;"><b>************</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px;">Payment Method</td>
            <td style="text-align: right; border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px; width: 150px; color: red;" colspan="1">************</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px;"><b>Total</b></td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid #808080; height: 25px; text-align: right; width: 150px; color: red;"><b>************</b></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use sessions and a backend like PHP to handle everything. So if you have your agreement already in place, just add the details like <?php echo $cust_name ?> etc, Really simple and tons of examples and ready made scripts available. Also turn the agreement into a pdf to email to the customer too adds a nice touch

Comment: @larrychambers Assuming that I search for wrong keywords. Could you please share some links to those examples / already made scripts? That might be the starting point for me.

Comment: Show an a example of your agreement and I will make you a basic working script with examples on how to add, change etc

Comment: What kind of document? PDF?

Comment: @larrychambers I did edit my post as per your request. Please let me know if anything else might be reqired.

Comment: @Mr.Jo PDF is not a requirement at this stage.

Comment: So the document should be a PHP page or what? I'm asking because I need to know which kind of document you want. For example you can do it in WooCommerce within a PHP page. So in this case it would be very easy to get the customer name for example.

Comment: I will have it done shortly and I never said a PDF was a requirement just a nice touch!!! And again a simple process to make any document into one.

Comment: @Mr.Jo sorry for misunderstanding. Yes, it will be generated in WooCommerce. Let's make it more clear: I will add a checkbox box with the link like [link](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-additional-acceptance-checkbox-checkout/) and when I click the link, it will show the finalized agreemnt. Than let customer read the agreement. Then I should email it maybe as a PDF attachment and also store it for myself.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. So to answer your question: Yes, you can do it with accessing the data from the checkout. And you can also attach it to a WooCommerce email. But all in all this will take about 2-3 hours of work so I think this can't be done here on SO within a simple question. I might know how to do this but this will take some time. So maybe we can get in touch via Skype: jaika113

Comment: @Mr.Jo thanks for your offer but my intention is to learn things in here. Of course it is an option but it will be my last choice after trying everything I can do. Thanks anyway mate!

Comment: @larrychambers are you close to any solution?

Comment: Is there anyone who may lead me to the right direction?